# Custom Radio Button Gallery

Tags: html, css

Hello there I have next code and is only one problem
when input is checked its not image left in li where is checked the input
I try few ways to fix this like setup same img on each li same like a
label but got other problems than :) is anyone can give some ideas?

```css
  .test2{
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      background: url(images/animal-small.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    .test3{
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      background: url(images/animal-small3.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    .test{
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      background: url(images/animal-small2.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    input{
      visibility: hidden
    }
    input:checked + label{
      padding: 10%;
      position: fixed;
      top:150px;
      left: 150px;
      display: block;
      background-size: 400px , 400px;
      border: 1px solid black
    }
    li{
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
    }
    li :hover{
      cursor: pointer;
      background-size: 110px  110px
    }
```

```html
<body>
    
     <ul>
      <li>
       <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test">
       <label for="test" class="test"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
       <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test2">
       <label for="test2" class="test2"></label>
      </li>
      <li>
       <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test3">
       <label for="test3" class="test3"></label>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

OP request is to have a thumbnail image and the enlarged image for a more intuitive navigation of the gallery. Changed the layout a little and adjusted the CSS to accommodate the extra element (`<figure>`.)

---

Avoid repeating code, condense styles together.

> when input is checked its not image left in li

I suspect the urls are not pointing to the image files. A slightly adapted version in the following Snippet is successful displaying pictures.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.test1,
.test2,
.test3 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test1 {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1) no-repeat;
}
.test2 {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50/00f/eee?text=2) no-repeat;
}
.test3 {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50/0e0/111?text=3) no-repeat;
}
input,
input + figure.img {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + figure.img {
  padding: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  display: block;
  background-size: 400px, 400px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
li:hover {
  background-size: 110px 110px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="test1" class="test1">
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test1">
          <figure class='img test1'></figure>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="test2" class="test2">
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test2">
          <figure class='img test2'></figure>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="test3" class="test3">
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="" id="test3">
          <figure class='img test3'></figure>
        </label>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: thx for suggestins but this dont answer my question :( still when u checked number 1 no img left in li

Comment: Use the developer tools  by right clicking one of the enlarged images. It is the label inside the li. Nothing has disappeared from li.

Comment: ok i will change my question :) "how to make even when is checked 1 to be image display on both position " i dont want the small one to disappear from the top when is selected

Comment: cool now is work they way i like .... btw i can see what u did but dont understand maybe have to read about figure :) let me know if i need to know anything else that u made to work this one

Comment: `<figure>` is just a fancy `<div>`. It's companion, `<figcaption>` can be nested within `<figure>` for a brief text description. Semantically, it's for visual content that informs through illustration like images, charts, etc.

Comment: Significant changes to CSS: `input + figure.img {...} ` and `input:checked + figure.img {...}`

Comment: that really helpful sir , u make my day better i will try <figcaption> to see how is work , see you around

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, sir. Happy coding.:)